# Select 4 users profile pictures, that participate in an event (mysql)

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am using the following query to get information about a meetup (an event), from my database. I want to be able to select 4 users (who participates in the event) profile pictures.

```
SELECT
    m.meetup_name,
    m.url_meetup,
    LEFT(m.meetup_text, 120) as teaser,
    DATE_FORMAT(m.datetime, "%d-%m-%Y <br> %I:%i") as datetime,
    a.username,
    a.url_username,
    c.city_name,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM meetup_participants mp WHERE MP.meetup_id = m.id) as participants
FROM
meetups m, users a, cities c
WHERE
    a.id = m.author_id
    AND c.postalcode = m.postalcode
```

My tables look like:

```
meetup =>
  id
  meetup_name
  url_meetup
  meetup_text
  author_id
  datetime
  ......

meetup_participants =>
  meetup_id
  user_id

users
  id
  username
  url_username
  profile_picture
```

I would strongly prefer not to use any more subqueries. My first thought was i could do it through the subquery i already have, but then i found out i can only return one column from a subquery.

I hope someone, has an idea how this can be accomplished.

Comment: In my opinion you would be much better off just writing two queries, I suspect the complexity of making a single query would not be worth the (potential) performance difference of two queries, in fact, two queries may be faster still.

Comment: The thing is that i am showing these events in some boxes, and have several of them. I even have a search page where the users can search for events. That means i would have to do that 16 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with using CONCAT in a subquery, and use php to split the string into an array:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(u.url_username,"/60_thumb/",u.profile_picture)) FROM meetup_participants mp, users u WHERE mp.meetup_id = m.id AND u.id = mp.user_id LIMIT 4) AS participants_pictures
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your tables correctly, this should get the first four participants found for a meeting. It connects the users through the `meetup_participants` resolution table.

```
SELECT
  m.meetup_name,
  m.url_meetup,
  LEFT(m.meetup_text, 120) as teaser,
  DATE_FORMAT(m.datetime, "%d-%m-%Y <br> %I:%i") as datetime,
  a.username,
  a.url_username,
  c.city_name,
  mp.picture -- or whatever you need to get from meeting_participants
FROM meetups
INNER JOIN meetup_participants mp ON m.id = m.meetup_id
INNER JOIN users a ON mp.user_id = a.id
INNER JOIN cities c ON m.postalcode = c.postalcode
WHERE m.whatever = 'whatever identifies the event'
ORDER BY a.username -- or whatever is important to you, or don't ORDER the results
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Thats not it sorry. A meetup can have many participants. The query i have gets me a list of meetups, with information about the meetup and the author. And what i want, is to also get profile_picture of 4 people participating in each meetup.